# Is stepping into lambda expressions broken in VS2013?

Tags: c#, debugging, lambda, visual-studio-2013, step-into

In VS2010 and VS2012 I can step into lambda expression when current statement is displayed for the **in** part of the **foreach** loop:

[image: StepInto lambda expression]

I just had to press **f11**:

[image: StepInto lambda expression VS2010]

In VS2013 this is broken. When I hit **f11**, current statement goes directly to loop variable:

[image: StepInto lambda expression VS2013]

I can still get into lambda expression by putting breakpoint for `i % 2 == 0` expression, but simple f11 is so much easier...
Is this a bug in VS2013 or do I miss some setting or something?

Comment: I just tried this, and it's working OK for me (I put the breakpoint on `in` and when I press `F11` it goes to `i%2 == 0`)

Comment: So it looks like it is my environment. Always better than broken VS... Do you know any setting which can drive such behavior, by the chance?

Comment: I can't think of anything. I even checked with Code Contracts enabled and with a Code Contract in the same method (because I had problems with those in the past) but it's all ok. I don't think it would be anything to do with the "Just My Code" setting, but maybe worth checking that?

Comment: Who marked this as "off-topic"? Perhaps whoever it was should [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which specifically states that you can ask about `software tools commonly used by programmers` - such as, for example, Visual Studio...

Comment: "Just My Code" did the trick. Thanks Matthew for the tip. If you post your comment again as an answer, I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have the "Just My Code" debugging option turned on.

Go to Options -> Debugging -> General and ensure that "Enable just my code" is unselected.

Comment: Sorry to be sticking my oar in months after this was first answered (and for being a pedantic Pat!) but I had the same problem and thank you Matthew for the answer but should it not state that "Enable just my code" is **unselected**?

Comment: @Tomás Hah, yes - I guess the OP realised what I meant. I'll update for future reader. :)